# Index aren't being updated for GAE data store

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a `BoardPost` entity with an index on `created_at`.  I am able to create this entity and fetch it by key, but when I try to fetch all objects within the last 24 hours and sorted by `created_at`, I only end up with posts from many hours ago. This exact query has been working the entire time, but as far as I can tell has suddenly stopped working. In fact all queries beside direct key gets seem to be stuck in time, as if indexes have stopped updating.

I looked on the app engine indexes dashboard and all indexes appear to be serving. I've also flushed memcached. This is a staging environment so instances are sporadically online. Also, yesterday I switched the version number, set it default, and deleted the old version. None of these actions should have stopped index building.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of us with same problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/?show_docid=fae072cf1c7db8b1#!topic/google-appengine/dRUabeuAoRo